# JavaScript LastFM

Tags: javascript, last.fm

Hi have the following function:

```
function last()
{
    /* Create a cache object */
    var cache = new LastFMCache();
    alert("test");

    alert("test2");
    /* Load some artist info. */
    lastfm.artist.getInfo({artist: 'The Killers'}, {success: function(data){
        alert(data.bio);
        $('gallery').append(data.to_html('<p>${bio}</p>'));
    }, error: function(code, message){
        /* Show error message. */
    }});
}
```

alert(data.bio) shows up as undefined. 
How would I check what data is being held and how can I used and format it correctly on my webpage?

Comment: `console.log(data)` will tell you quite a bit.  Also look at your network requests to see what's going on.

Comment: Where is `data` defined and where is `last()` called?

Comment: <button type="button" onclick="last()">Try it</button> its called here and i assume data is defined with the information is retrieved? That is where data is first used.

Comment: Can you show me in the code where `data` and `data.bio` is defined?

Comment: I'm not sure where it is defined. Don't think it is.

Comment: `data` is defined when specified as a parameter of the anonymous success callback function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I check what data is being held?

- Get Firefox, if you don't have it. Install Firebug. Bring up Firebug by pressing F12. Click on the Console tab. Put `console.log(data);` in your success callback function. Run the code, and inspect the contents at your heart's content. I recommend Firefox as having a superior object browser to Chrome, but you can also...
- Get Chrome. Its debugger is built in. press F12. Click on the Console tab. Do the same thing as I said for Firefox.

Knowledge acquired!